What is the difference between working focus distance and infinity focus in Camera Lens (specially machine vision camera)
I am new to camera lenses and am trying to understand their details. I have learned concepts like aperture, focal length, FOV, IRIS, and different mounts (C, CS type, etc.).
I have a question regarding focal length. By definition, "It is the distance between the lens and the plane of the sensor, and is determined when the lens focuses the object at infinity." So, I have drawn the following image to illustrate my understanding.
Light rays are parallel, as light from infinity (far objects) will have parallel rays.

When I started reviewing the datasheets like Basler (C12-5024-25M-P) I noticed they state that the lens has a working distance of 200mm and a minimum focus distance of 50mm.
I have a few doubts here:

Why is it that I cannot achieve infinity focus using such lenses? Is it because the lens cannot move far enough from the image sensor to focus on infinity?

If the minimum focal distance is 50mm and the working distance is 200mm (meaning the lens can focus on objects between 50mm to 200mm), does my diagram correctly represent what the lens is trying to achieve?

Why do lens manufacturers provide a resolution specification for a lens? Shouldn't it be infinite?




You have read the specifications wrong... but they are not written terribly clearly.
It is a 50mm lens with a 200mm minimum working distance. It can focus from 200mm to infinity. Note that it is only a 50mm lens when focused at infinity; at all other focus distances elements must move closer to the image plane/sensor. Therefore the true focal length changes somewhat.
The spec sheet also states that the maximum lens resolution is at f/2.77; which means that at apertures wider than that optical aberrations reduce resolution; and diffraction is reducing resolution at apertures smaller than that. Maximum resolution is almost always a balancing act... Also note that the specification is only for the 1.2" sensor format noted. All other smaller formats will have a lower maximum resolution, because they record less of the projected image circle.


No its because the lens cannot move close enough to the sensor(*). Its the same problem as SLR cameras using a macro extender rings on the lens. The camera can focus closer, but it's "far" focus is no longer at infinity.
No because to focus at 200mm the lens is closer to the sensor than when focusing at 50mm.
If the lenses where actually thin lenses and used with small angles (in other words for a very small area at the center) and monochrome light then yes, but then there is this pesky real world where the refractive index depends on wavelength and users want wide fields so you have to combine multiple elements and even then you cannot get a perfect focus which reduces the attainable resolution.

(*) See Wikipedia. To focus to a close object (smaller S1), the lens has to be farther from the object plane (wider S2).

Focal length is that distance from lens to focused image when the subject is at an infinite distance, like a star. We test indoors on an optical bench using an artificial star, a point source that outputs parallel rays. The shape of the lens and the density of the material of construction change the path of the light rays as they traverse the lens. The rays are bent inward such that they converge. This action is called refraction from Latin to bend backwards.
Light rays from objects closer than infinity arrive at the lens as diverging rays (not parallel).
Because the lens has limited ability to refract, the distance lens to focused image becomes elongated. As we image closer and closer the projection distance becomes longer and longer. If the image of the object is life-size (actual size), the projection distance will be twice the focal length and the distance object to focused image will be 4X the focal length.
We refer to this lengthened projection distance as “back focus” distance. Suppose a 50mm is working an object 100mm forward of the lens. What will be the revised lens to image distance? First find the power of the lens is diopter units. 1/50 X 1000 =20d. Convert 100mm to diopter power. 1/100 X 1000 = 10d. Subtract 20d – 10d = 10d. Convert 10d to diopter units 1/10 X 1000 = 1000mm (working projection distance object 100mm distant. Further, the f-number engraved on the lens is now in error. See Bellows Effect. The error is 2 f-stops reduced, we are dividing the working diameter of the lens into the projection distance, not the focal length that is used when the object is at infinity.
All lenses have defects that reduce the quality of the image (aberrations). The lens maker strives to yield a faithful image. To achieve this, the camera lens is constructed of many individual lens elements. Some are convex, some are concave, some are dense material, some less dense.
Additionally, twin demons called diffraction and interference impede resolution. As the working diameter is reduced (stopping down), diffraction and interference begin to take their toll. Most lenses will have a sweet setting that is two f-stops down from max diameter.  Look up Rayleigh Criterion.
Further in the specifications the range is given as infinity to 200mm.
